# Gnu/Linux: Listing files, with certain characters in the file-name, while in a different directory

Tags: linux, centos, find, ls, path

How do I list all files and directories in the `/etc/` directory, **which have one or more digits in its file-name**, and save the output to a file, in the home directory.

The output must have the full path (eg. `/etc/filename`). I've tried to do it using the `ls` command, but failed to do so. Also while using the `find` command I didn't succeed.

Comment: What did you try and what was the result ?

Comment: There are two questions in here. “How do I list all files and directories in the /etc/ directory, which have one or more digits in its file-name, **and** save the output to a file, in the home directory.” Please one question per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use several ways:

```
ls -lR /etc >~/file
find /etc >~/file
```

Check the outputs and select the desired

Based on your edited question you can use command like:

```
find /etc |grep -E '[0-9]'
```

Comment: I'm sorry I have just edited my question. I want to list all files and directories in the /etc/ directory which have one or more numbers in its' file name

Comment: @AmrA.EL-Amrawy, check my edited answer

Comment: Thank you, Romeo. Is there a way to use ls instead of find here?

Comment: @AmrA.EL-Amrawy, I do not know the way to make `ls` to show path and filename in one line. The samples is IMO with `find`